# Función rand() me genera valores no imprimibles

Tags: c

Estoy usando la función `srand(time(NULL))` y `rand()` para generar valores aleatorios en una matriz, pero he visto que me genera valores no imprimibles y no se visualizan en la matriz, me aparece un espacio vacío. Cada vez que ejecuto el código, estos espacios vacíos se encuentran en distintas posiciones.

Adjunto el código, ¿A qué se puede deber?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define O 4
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 int b[O],max, A[O][O];
 int j,k,x,l,m,n,suma;
 printf("Dame las 4 componentes del vector b: \n");
 for(int i=0;i<O;i++)
 {
  scanf("%d",&b[i]);
  printf("La componente b[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i]);
 }
 srand(time(NULL));
 max=(b[0]>b[1] && b[0]>b[2] && b[0]>b[3])? b[0]: (b[1]>b[2] && b[1]>b[3])? b[1]: (b[2]>b[3])? b[2]:b[3];
 printf("El maximo numero dentro del vector es: %d\n",max);
 for (l=0;l<O;l++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<O;j++)
            {
                A[j][l] = rand()%11;
                printf("%3.d", A[j][l]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quítale el punto `.` al `printf("%3.d", A[j][l]);`

Comment: Sí era eso, ya lo quité y lo ejecuté y ya sale correctamente. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.